# Generic way of allowing all running tasks to complete before finishing the current async method (wpf)?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

wpf

I have a main window which opens several UserControls in their own Window Dialogs. The UserControls each have their own ViewModel.
These user controls in turn have multiple custom controls. To be highly modular, I am allowing the custom controls to use asnyc/await to read/write to the network server.

Each UserControl can be closed by the user by clicking on the right-upper "X". When this happens, program execution is passed to the OnWindowClosingAsync handler within the UserControl's ViewModel.

```
public async Task OnWindowClosingAsync(object s, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowDialog w = (WindowDialog)s;
        if (OkToClose)
        {

            e.Cancel = false;  // e.Cancel = false allows closing the window.
            return;
        }
        OkToClose = false;

        // Cancel window closure until all running tasks have completed..
        e.Cancel = true;        // e.Cancel = true keeps window open.
        w.IsEnabled = false;    // Consider w.Hide().  Stop further user interaction with this window. (Window is dimmed).

        ....more code ...

        await Task.Yield();  <--**FAILS TO WAIT FOR OTHER TASKS TO COMPLETE.
        OkToClose = true;


        WritingLayer.Dispose();

        // Manually closing the windowdialog will force reentry into OnWindowClosingAsync(), (i.e., this procedure).
        w.Close();
    }
```

The idea I was hoping for was that Task.Yield will put the OnWindowClosingAsync() code following the Task.Yield to the bottom of the Task que and allow any currently running task to complete before moving on to close the UserControl. THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK ofcourse. Clearly, Task.Yield is adding the code that follows it to be run asynchronously, but it does not force other running tasks to complete before it continues. (Like tasks that save data).

So is there a good generic way of allowing all running tasks (regardless of their context) to complete before executing the code following Task.Yield?

TIA

Comment: Just a little advice if you're open to it... placing ```OnWindowClosingAsync``` in the ViewModel is terrible and for that reason it's no longer a ViewModel.  I suggest rethinking this completely.  As far as the tasks; you shouldn't need to wait for all concurrent tasks to complete; if you have a concrete set of tasks running that you want to remember and await then you can capture those and use ```await Task.WhenAll(yourListOfTasks)``` or similar.  As far as queuing that is managed differently and you can't yield or delay or do anything to queue yourself to being last.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII  Your advice is appreciated. Thanks. In a previous version I was using Task.WhenAll, but ultimately, that required each custom control to update a single class (similar to an event aggregator) which then was being polled by the close event in the viewmodel class. I was hopeful that Task.Yield would post itself to the end of the que allowing any running task to complete first. (The documentation on Task.Yield, to me at least, is a bit confusing). Oh well, back to the drawing board. Thanks. :)

Comment: ```Task.Yield``` simply signals the remaining code (yields it) to be queued to run on the current context.  The ```SynchronizationContext``` is what decides the priority and order or the tasks.  Maybe this will help; a thread can only operate one step at a time; those steps are grouped into methods; meaning the thread now performs a method at a time.  So example: if a you have a long method running on the UI thread and the user starts clicking a button; you've seen this before most likely... the user clicks will do nothing until the long running method is complete; then after all those....

Comment: ...clicks will be fired at once.  This is because the user interaction is still queued up.  So look at it like this.  The ```SynchronizationContext``` basically takes a queue of commands to run and based on information about each command, it runs them as soon as it can; one at a time.  If you have a long running method and you don't want to block the UI then you can schedule the work to be off loaded to another thread.  Here's where ```Task``` and ```async / await``` kicks in to do some magic.  When you label a method ```async``` then you are telling the compiler that the method has...

Comment: ...the potential to be broken up into multiple methods (or basically it can be queued dynamically at certain intervals.)  Those intervals are decided when we call ```await```.  What we do is schedule a callback from the ```Task``` we ```await``` and place the rest of the method in a dynamic method.  When the ```Task``` is complete the remaining work (dynamic method) is then placed in the queue to be ran by the ```SynchronizationContext```.  Now... All that said just to show you that when you call ```await Task.Yield()``` you're simply throwing the remaining method into the queue immediately...

Comment: ...This means the remaining work can be scheduled to run next or last or whenever the ```SynchronizationContext``` decides.  For this reason ```Task.Yield``` was added incase you want to break up the current context from within the same method.  My example may not be the best but it's what I chose to explain it.  The bottom line is stay away from ```Task.Yield``` as much as possible because it most likely indicates something was engineered wrong to start with.  There's a proper time and place for it and that may be debated but I wouldn't debate the abuse of it.

Comment: … And to come with circle... If you had that user clicking that button several times and that long running method was ```async``` and portions were broken up with ```await Task.Yield``` it MIGHT allow some of those clicks to process making the user experience smoother.  However; MS strongly discourages this and recommends NOT using ```Task.Yield``` to keep a UI responsive simply because we cannot know what the ```SynchronizationContext``` will choose next to run and it could possibly end up running the same method inline anyway.

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense and helps you understand why ```Task.Yield``` isn't working for you and possibly clarifies the documentation for you a bit.  Otherwise it's all jibber jabber and regardless isn't mean to answer your question.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Very Very helpful -- and not jibber jabber! Much appreciated. Slightly off topic, is there ever a place for Task.Yield with current multiple cpu's? (if you wrote this as an answer I would gladly credit it as such). Thanks.

Comment: I believe when you engineer something; if you're purpose can be explained from start to finish and is working, then it would be correct.  Whether that implementation has benefits being done differently is debatable to a degree; following common guidelines is the overall best practice.  Still yet; I don't believe ```Task.Yield``` is beneficial for multi-core processing.  I believe it's main use; and I may be corrected, would be to insure an asynchronous method does become asynchronous.  Here's an example: ...

Comment: … A method call that is ```async``` may or may not return immediately or switch contexts. Meaning, just because it is ```async``` doesn't mean it will be asynchronous.  If my method returns ```Task.Run(() => …)``` then by all means I'm returning an asynchronous running ```Task``` but if my method has options and one option returns ```Task.Run(() => …)``` and the other just returns ```new Person()``` for example; then my ```async``` method has the potential to be synchronous instead of asynchronous.  To prevent areas of deadlock or prevent areas of performance where the method is assumed...

Comment: ... to be asyhchrnous we can call ```await Task.Yield``` to insure the method becomes asynchronous.  This way, even though the method may not need to always be awaited, we can ```await``` it with the same logic that the remaining portion is scheduled to run later. It basically gives us the option to insure our method performs like we say it does.  So for my example... if we return ```new Person()``` we should first call ```await Task.Yield()``` and then return ```new Preson()``` so that anyone using it gets similar results awaiting it like they would if we returned ```Task.Run(() => )```

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Excellent sir. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII  Last question, as I am new at this, is there a good example of how to correctly close a window when waiting for some tasks to complete? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I don't believe there's any specific answer because this depends on your use case but using the VM to handle window events is bad. My first impulse would be to tell you to collect the tasks that you're sure you need to await and place them in a static list or common collector of some sort and when you choose to close you can choose some closing animation possibly and ```await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks)```.  Of course you mentioned being aware of this so this probably doesn't fit your needs. This could be answered if we had more information about the application and your intentions.

Comment: *"So is there a good generic way of allowing all running tasks (regardless of their context) to complete before executing the code following Task.Yield?"*? Yes, await them all using `Task.WhenAll`.